# Adding include paths and lib files in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw

Recently, I have begun wanting to learn OpenGl, and in the tutorial they are using a static GLFW library to make the code concise and cross platform, but I use VS code, and they use Visual Studio. I use CMake to link my libraries so how would I do that with a lib file and the .h files respectively?

I thought you could achieve this as so

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(openGL VERSION 1.0.0)

include_directories(${workspaceFolder}dev\dependencies\GLFW\include)
link_directories(${workspaceFolder}dev\dependencies\GLFW\lib-vc2019)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${workspaceFolder}dev\dependencies\GLFW\include)
```

but this does not seem to work

If anyone knows how I could complete this, please show me. I have respect for all of you. I am quite a young programmer, but I want to be able to do big things, and I would like to start by working on nice graphical interfaces.

Comment: `target_link_libraries` should specify target name and library name. Take a look at the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: "but this does not seem to work" is not a description with which we can help you. What exactly doesn't work? Do you got an error? If yes, then show the error message. See also [ask].